# Sort negative elements from an array

Tags: c, arrays, negative-number

This is part of a code I am writing as an assigment in C.
What I am trying to do is to detect negative numbers in an array and fill another array with these negative numbers. Meanwhile, I'd like to count those negative numbers.

All of this sounds pretty easy and everything seems to work out until I try to print the number of negative elements. This is what I get:
*6422204 numbers are negative.*

I simply cannot figure out what is wrong, or even if this is the good way to do it.

Here's the code:

```
double arr[10] = {21, -3.4, 65, 7.6, -12, 66, 10, -2, 5, 135};

int length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(double);
printf("There are %d numbers in the array.\n",length);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("[%d]=%.1lf ", i, arr[i]);
}

int neg = 0;
double negative[10];

for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    if(arr[j] < 0)
    {
        negative[j] = arr[j];
        neg++;
    }
}

printf("\n\n%d numbers are negative.", &neg);
```

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: `&neg` - remove the `&`.

Comment: You are printing the address of `neg`.

Comment: I suggest you also use a different indexing variable than `j` for the output array. Wherever there is a non-negative value, you skip that element in `negative` which then remains uninitilaised. I suggest you index with`neg`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Actually, `neg` should work just fine for that, don't you think?

Comment: @FredLarson yes but that is not what OP is doing, but using `j` as I wrote.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I know. I was just suggesting that `neg` is already there and would be good for indexing `negative`.

Comment: @FredLarson thank you for your help.

Comment: Consider just putting `negative[neg++] = arr[j];` inside the `if`. That will remove the gaps in your `negative` array.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `&` in `printf`:

```
printf("\n\n%d numbers are negative.", neg);
```